'cygpath is not available, fallback to manual path conversion'
following 'conda deactivate' to use virtual venv I receive 'cygpath is not available'.

what is this and how to resolve?
(.venv) (base) 
02acl@ali_ah MINGW64 C:/Users/02acl/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code
$ conda deactivate
cygpath is not available, fallback to manual path conversion
cygpath is not available, fallback to manual path conversion
cygpath is not available, fallback to manual path conversion

cygwin is installed:
$ cygcheck -V
cygcheck (msys) 3.3.6
System Checker for Msys
Copyright (C) 1998 - 2023 Cygwin Authors


Are you sure that you have cygwin installed? What does cygcheck -V show?

@user1934428 thanks for commenting: cygcheck is installed

I cygcheck hope that you executed the cygcheck command after conda deactivate. With this in mind, I wonder how the conda command invokes cygpath. Assuming that type cygcheck and type cygpath show you the same directory (did you verify this?), I would suspect a bug in conda.
